# Searching for lists of words in order in a string

Tags: python

I have 3 lists of words. To put them simply:

1. question
2. subject
3. verb

I want to look for any word in the list in a string and if there's at least one match from all the lists it returns true but only if it's in the same order as I wrote above in the string.
Example: "Is ... object ... verb"

`if any(word in msg for word in questions) and any(word in msg for word in object) and any(word in msg for word in verb):`

Comment: Please provide a concrete example, it's not super clear what "only if it's in the same order as I wrote above in the string" means.

Comment: I did. "question ... object ... verb". Theres a string, and it should be looking for the words in the list in the order that I wrote. 1.question 2.object 3.verb. "*is* the *thing* *working* as intended?"

Comment: "I want to look for any word in the list in a string" is not even remotely clear. Please provide a [minimal reproducible example](https://stackoverflow.com/help/minimal-reproducible-example). Please also see [how to ask a good question](https://stackoverflow.com/help/how-to-ask).

Comment: question = ["is", "how"]
object = ["thing", "person"]
verb = ["close" "open" "doing"]

string that it should recognize:
"how is the person doing?"

strings it shoudn't:
"doing the person is how"

"how is the person"

Comment: What about `"is person doing?"` or `"how thing close"`? Are those "valid" despite being grammatically incorrect?

Comment: exactly. someone already sent a working code tho, thanks anyway :)

Answer (score 0, accepted):

From what I understand about your question, you may try this:

```
def check_list_againt_list(l1 , l2):
    found = [i for i in l1 if i in l2]
    if found:
        return found, l2.index(found[0])
    else:
        return None, None

questions = ['what' , 'when', 'how', 'which']
subjects = ["artist", "student" , "teacher", "doctor"]
verbs = ["teach", "read", "jump", "sing"]
string = "how can a teacher sing?"
string = ''.join(c for c in string if c not in ',?')

question, q_index = check_list_againt_list(questions, string.split(" "))
subject, s_index = check_list_againt_list(subjects, string.split(" "))
verb, v_index = check_list_againt_list(verbs, string.split(" "))

if None not in [q_index, s_index, v_index]:
    if q_index < s_index < v_index:
        print(True)
    else:
        print(False)
else:
    print(False)
```

Let me know whether it's what you want.